# contains placeholder within quotes error AWS Cloudwatch rule

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to use an AWS Cloudwatch rule that runs a powershell script on a EC2 Instance using SSM. The script works when I hard code the instance ID in the command section of the RunPowerShellScript Document. But when I use the same command in the Input Transformer to get the Instanceid as a variable from the Cloudwatch event I get the following error:

> "There was an error while saving rule DisableInAD. Details:
>   InputTemplate for target Id111111 contains placeholder within
>   quotes.."

The input Command I am trying to use is: `{"commands":["C:\\users
\\documents\\Disable_Single_Instance -Id <instance>"]}`

Comment: Did you resolve this. Having the same problem. If i put the placeholder outside the quotes, it is valid but the script doesnt receive the parameters, instead it tries to call the _script.sh with each one as if they are separate commands.  If placed inside the quotes, i get the same error you got.  In my case, this is on linux but it's via RunCommand in AWS System Manager so same problem.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I asked AWS about this and was told that this is a known limitation of Cloudwatch Events Input Transformer. They suggested creating a Lambda to use as the target as you are able to pass parameters that way. Then the lambda could potentially invoke the SSM command.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to escape the quotes

e.g.:

InputPathsMap

```
{"pipeline":"$.detail.pipeline","state":"$.detail.state"}
```

InputTemplate

```
"{\"message\":\"<pipeline> - <state>\"}"
```

In cloud formation:

```
InputTransformer:
  InputPathsMap: 
    pipeline: "$.detail.pipeline"
    state: "$.detail.state"
  InputTemplate: '"{\"message\":\"<pipeline> - <state>\"}"'
```

You will get the result as a quoted string (not JSON) e.g.

```
"\"{\\\"message\\\":\\\"TestPipleline - SUCCEEDED\\\"}\""
```

so you will have double parse the result to get the proper JSON.